# Implementation of power view in sp 2013 - Pain Points and Ideas

Tags: 2013, excel-services, reports, powerpivot

Can anybody please give me some painpoints of using PowerView in sharepoint 2013.

Recently in our project we are planning to upgrade our site from SP2010 to 2013. In SP2010 site we have lots of reports in silverlight. We were using Telerik controls along with Silverlight to show user different graphical representation of data (pie chart, details table, etc). As Silverlight is not being used in SP2013 we are thinking of moving these reports in powerview as this is the perfect solution for us.

So it will be very much helpful for me if anybody can guide me exactly how we can integrate powerView reports in sharepoint 2013 and also the issues faced while doing this.

Thanks In Advance

Alam

Answer (score 1):

The main issue will be getting SQL Server 2012 SP1 in integrated mode with SharePoint 2013.  Once you crack that then Power View seems to work very nicely - either from an Excel 2013 spreadsheet or from a Tabular data set.  You can actually build the Power View visualisations just in Excel 2013 now and then simply upload them to SharePoint to facilitate sharing with others.  Once uploaded then you can create other Power View reports on that file as a source as you used to in 2010.  If you take this route then you can also then export to PowerPoint as you used to in 2010.

Hope this helps and good luck.